# using proxy on session via python

Tags: python, session, proxy, request

i want make a session in python and send request but with using proxy like this

```
import requests
file = open("pro.txt", "r")
rr = file.readlines()
for i in rr:
    try:
        def get_session():
            session = requests.session()
            aa = "{}".format(i)
            print(aa)
            session.proxies = {'https':  "https://"+aa}
            return session
        
        session = get_session()
        print(session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
        
        print(requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
    except:
        continue
```

i think it's using proxy but the problem is responses they return ip  of request, anyway, both of them return the same ip, i except frist response be the same with that proxy is using, so why the responses are the same?

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong function name( `get_tor_session`) because you defined it as `get_session`
so your code will look something like this

```
import requests
file = open("pro.txt", "r")
rr = file.readlines()
for i in rr:
    try:
        def get_session():
            session = requests.session()
            aa = "{}".format(i)
            print(aa)
            session.proxies = {'https':  "https://"+aa}
            return session
        
        session = get_session()
        print(session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
        
        print(requests.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: sorry that was a edit mistake